# SMTP send mail is not working for office365

Tags: java, office365, jakarta-mail

Here is a peculiar problem. The intention is to send a mail via SMTP for office365.

I have been able to consistently send mail from my local laptop.

But when deployed on our server (behind a firewall), it does not succeed. **Note:** The port 587 for `smtp.office365.com` is accessible and confirmed on the server. Here are the properties via which it successfully works from my local computer.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", MAIL_TIMEOUT);
props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", MAIL_TIMEOUT);
props.put("mail.debug", true);
this.session = Session.getInstance(props);
session.setDebug(true);

Transport transport  = session.getTransport();
transport.connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, email, pass);
```

But fails on server. Here are the server debug logs:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.office365.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 PN1PR0101CA0017.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 28 Jun 2019 06:39:41 +0000
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.office365.com", port: 587
EHLO appqa
250-PN1PR0101CA0017.outlook.office365.com Hello [182.73.191.100]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "157286400"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2155)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:752)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
at com.company.app.MailReader.getTransport(MailReader.java:269)
at io.vavr.control.Try.of(Try.java:75)
at com.company.app.MailReader.<init>(MailReader.java:59)
at com.company.services.MailService.getNewMailReader(MailService.java:82)
at com.company.services.MailService.start(MailService.java:46)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:34)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:593)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:529)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:626)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:553)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2150)
... 8 more
```

Comment: Try some of the debugging properties described in the Debugging section of [SSLNOTES.txt](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/docs/SSLNOTES.txt).  There may be problems with your JDK configuration, or you may have a firewall or anti-virus problem interposing on your connection and causing problems with the SSL certificate verification.

Comment: So you have tested with `telnet smtp.office365.com 587` on the server? are you able to connect? Is there is any proxy settings involved?

Comment: Yes. As mentioned above, it is able to connect and do the initial handshake

Comment: *Update*: Firewall and antivirus was disabled. Still it isnt working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was one particular rule in firewall.

Deleting the rule in the firewall fixed this issue. No specific code change was needed to make it work.

Comment: Can you tell us the rule that you have deleted ? @Jatin

Comment: Dont exactly remember. @SolomonRaja

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the server has the same set of certificates as your local computer.

The 220 response from the server does not mean that the TLS session is already established, it just means that the client may start negotiating it:

> After receiving a 220 response to a STARTTLS command, the client MUST start the TLS negotiation before giving any other SMTP commands.  If, after having issued the STARTTLS command, the client finds out that some failure prevents it from actually starting a TLS handshake, then it SHOULD abort the connection.
>   (from RFC 3207)

At this point, a missing certificate is the most likely problem.

Comment: Interesting part. This is something that I have not tried. Though I am using the same build of JDK (Adapt Jdk). Is there system level certificates that I should try? (I am not sure if JDK reads the system certificates though). Any guidance on specific item that I can try?

Comment: @Jatin: System certificates are not read. - But why did you mention the JDK? Office365 is not written in Java ... You need to ask your email admins for the certificates they installed on the MTA to install them with your JRE/JDK.

Comment: When I mean JDK, I mean the JDK installed on the system (application), that is trying to connect with O365 mailbox. JDK needs to have the certificates available.

> On your point of certificates installation, how is it then  that it works from other computers? There is nothing special done on  other computers. It is only the specific server where it isn't work. And the firewall and antivirus has been disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Check your **JRE version** on the server and compare it to the version of your local computer.

This is an environment related issue as the same code behaves differently on different machines. Without the full picture, I cannot answer with certainty. But I hope providing some insight for further investigation. My analysis follows:

- First, I don't think it's a SSL certificate issue, the root cause error is clear:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
...
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
...
```

this means the socket has been established, but the handshake phase of converting the socket to TLS has failed. If the certificate is not valid, it will be reported after the handshake, let's look at the code from the SocketFetcher.java class:

```java
    /*
     * Force the handshake to be done now so that we can report any
     * errors (e.g., certificate errors) to the caller of the startTLS
     * method.
     */
    sslsocket.startHandshake();

    /*
     * Check server identity and trust.
     */
    boolean idCheck = PropUtil.getBooleanProperty(props,
                prefix + ".ssl.checkserveridentity", false);
    if (idCheck)
        checkServerIdentity(host, sslsocket);
    if (sf instanceof MailSSLSocketFactory) {
        MailSSLSocketFactory msf = (MailSSLSocketFactory)sf;
        if (!msf.isServerTrusted(host, sslsocket)) {
        throw cleanupAndThrow(sslsocket,
            new IOException("Server is not trusted: " + host));
        }
    }
    }
```

the socket encountered the timeout at this line: `sslsocket.startHandshake()`, which is before the certificate validation.

- Second, you have already mentioned that firewalls are disabled, and we can see that the previous socket is correctly established so is the telnet command, so I don't think it's a firewall issue neither.
- It seems like a protocol issue, mostly because this happened during the handshake phase, otherwise we should see different and more explicit error, such as certificate error, connection timeout, etc. This is a **socketRead** timeout, which indicates the client (your server) is expecting some information from the server (office365), but the server doesn't respond, it's like they are not talking together.
- The compiled code is not the issue here, but some part of this process is environment related: the `SSLSocketImpl.class` class is from the JRE not from the compilation. And this is the exact code (decompiled) where the protocol is implemented:

```java
private void performInitialHandshake() throws IOException {
        Object var1 = this.handshakeLock;
        synchronized(this.handshakeLock) {
            if (this.getConnectionState() == 1) {
                this.kickstartHandshake();
                if (this.inrec == null) {
                    this.inrec = new InputRecord();
                    this.inrec.setHandshakeHash(this.input.r.getHandshakeHash());
                    this.inrec.setHelloVersion(this.input.r.getHelloVersion());
                    this.inrec.enableFormatChecks();
                }

                this.readRecord(this.inrec, false);
                this.inrec = null;
            }

        }
    }
```

The above code is from JRE_1.8.0_181, your code or the code from your server may be different. This is way it's necessary to check your server's JRE version.

- Using the same code you provided at the beginning, I could correctly connect to office365

Comment: Hi. I have verified. Both of them use the same JVM build. 
In fact, I redownloaded the JDK build from the same site and tried it.

Comment: Hi, ok this exludes the JRE issue. Let's move on, can you tell the value of the propertiy: `MAIL_TIMEOUT` please?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your properties, and it should do the trick.

```
props.getProperties().put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.office365.com");
```

Comment: Tried before. Doesn't help.